# How to add file inside folder of a zip

Tags: ubuntu, zip, files-folders

How do I add a file/folder in a zip file that isn't in the root folder? For example in

test.zip\parent test folder\folder1

and I want to add test1.txt inside the \folder1 of the zip file?

I am using ubuntu 22.04 and also windows 10 x64 enterprise

Answer (score 1):

1. Create folder structure same as in zip `mkdir -p "parent test folder/folder1"`
2. Put your file in needed folder `cp file "parent test folder/folder1"`
3. Add file to zip: `zip -g xxx.zip "parent test folder/folder1/file"`

More on matter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289734/linux-how-to-add-a-file-to-a-specific-folder-within-a-zip-file)

Comment: Is there no simpler way to do this ? I know on windows 7zip GUI, i can just drag and drop a folder from one zip archive to another retaining the date modified but the date created and date accessed is erased. With winRAR, same problem but the source zip file is saved in the temporary folder (I dont know why it does that). 7zip command line switch -mtc and -mta can preserve the timestamps but when putting it into the destination zip from a source zip file, an error is reported. What are other alternatives?

Comment: Ubuntu zip man page: [Options](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/zip.1.html#:~:text=in%20the%20future.-,OPTIONS,-%2Da%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2D%2Dascii%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5BSystems)

Comment: @anmac1789, It depends on what you mean by simpler, really. As mentioned in the linked stackoverflow answers you could create a symlink instead of creating a folder. Or you could write a small python script, that will provide you with the ability to do this as a single command. As for GUI alternatives: basically this is a limitation of the realization of cli `zip`, but you could create your own wrapper (as mentioned before), or try to use an alternative tool.

Comment: @anmac1789, regarding problems with 7zip, I don't know much about 7zip, and if you really want a chance to get an answer for this I recommend to create separate question. Because comment to answer is quite obscure, and not really convenient for this.

Comment: Ill just create a new post about 7zip and connect it to this post for additional details